# Why does iPhone navigation bar disappear when browsing certain sites?

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, facebook

When I click on the Facebook bookmark I saved to my home screen, m.facebook.com appears in Safari but the navigation bar at the bottom and the URL bar at the disappear.  At first I thought I was launching the Facebook app by mistake but I verified that's not the case.  Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Agreed I bounce between the app and webapp too. They have different bugs. And yes this behavior is annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, mobile sites can be programmed to remove the navigation bar whilst browsing the site.  Makes for a better user experience when these elements get out of the way.

This is documented here  http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

In particular the apple-mobile-web-app-capable element.

Comment: This doesn't seem to happen if I browse to facebook from the URL bar.  It seems to happen when I click on the saved link on my home screen.  I find this behavior annoying.  Any way to disable?

Comment: No, its programmed into the mobile version of facebook.  Any reason you don't use the Facebook app?

Comment: So whether I access Facebook via a saved bookmark on my home screen or via typing in the URL, aren't I accessing the mobile version of Facebook?  If so, why the different behavior?  I like using the web version of most sites, less switching between apps.  I do use the FB app occasionally when I want to post photos but I mostly use the mobile web site.

Comment: When you access a website via a bookmark on the home screen the rules over what a website can do are different. This allows sites that are added to the home screen to behave a little more like real apps. If you want to run the Facebook site, but stop it from hiding the navigation bar then you'll need to launch it within Safari.